# Triggered Send via ampscript in landing pages

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am adding a subscriber to the All Subs list via a landing page after which i would like to send them a welcome email.  What are my options to do this?

I was hoping to create a triggered send definition and invoke it using ampscript.  I tried this but nothing happens. I am assuming that here I need to supply the external key of the triggered send definition `SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "update-pref-email-en")`
and here I need to supply the MID of the Business Unit `SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", "xxxxx")`?

```
%%[

var @emailaddr
SET @emailaddr = 'xxx@exacttarget.com'
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_subkey = 'xxx@exacttarget.com'

SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "update-pref-email-en")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)

SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", @emailaddr)  
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)  

SET @attr = CreateObject("Attribute")
SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Name", "ChannelMemberID")
SetObjectProperty(@attr, "Value", "xxxxx")
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts_sub, "Attributes", @attr)

AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

]%%
```

Comment: How did you create the triggered send definition?  Within the app or API?  Can you verify that it is running?

Comment: Created the triggered send via the app.  It is working now had to recreate the triggered send definition.

Comment: Did you achieve finally this? I'm having any of issues trying to send an email with ampscript....